# Equivalent of unix command in batch command

Tags: batch-file

I have two unix commands which search particular string appearing in two files(Test1 & Test2). Can someone please help me provide the equivalent cmd commands for the below

1. cat Test1.log | grep "] ERROR"
2. cat Test2.log | grep "] ERROR"  | grep -v "string1:40" | grep - "string2:65" | grep -v "string3:41"

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Check if the string is in the file? Read the containing line?

Comment: useless use of `cat` :)

Comment: Michael.. I want to capture the error statements from the log files stored in a location and want to put them into a single file and send that file to my email automatically. If you require I can show it through an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
find "] ERROR" Test1.log

find "] ERROR" Test2.log|find /v "string1:40" | find "string2:65" | find /v "string3:41"
```

?

Check [FINDSTR](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) and [FIND](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a file contains a string you can use `FINDSTR "] ERROR" Test1.log` and evaluate `%errorlevel%` afterwards. If the string was found %errorlevel% will be `0` and if not it will be `0`. Something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
find "] ERROR" Test1.log
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 ECHO Error was found in the log!
```

Comment: Or [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution).  `find "] ERROR" Test1.log >NUL 2>NUL && echo error found.`

Comment: @Michael: One more assistance required- I want to get this error strings in Test1.log from a location directly. I mean my batch file would get the error messages from the logfiles stored in a specific location automatically and copy the messages containing error string to a new file. How can I specify the path find "] ERROR" Test*.log if the test log let's say in the path C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\LogTest  and add the output to a new  file.